# Display records page wise using ASP.NET with C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have created web page that retrieves data from MS SQL database and display it to the user in well formatted manner. Data retrieved depend upon criteria selected by the user. But sometimes data retrieved is very large. I want to display records to the user page wise, i.e. 100 records on first page and next 100 records displayed when user clicks next button. This means only 100 records should be retrieved when user first select search criteria, next 100 records retrieved when he clicks next button and so on, as to reduce data transferred from server to client.

Please suggest me how to achieve this as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you retrieving data? For example, Entity Framework, Linq-to-SQL

Comment: @codersnet Are you using WebMatrix?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called **paging**.

This can be done a million ways. You mention jquery, javascript and asp.net. For displaying purpose that is quite all righ but for good performance you want to make sure that the actual selection of the page has to be done at the backend.

One approach is this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx This is not jquery but it shows a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) or [DataTables](http://datatables.net/.).  Both are very popular grids

Ask user to set there criteria and then render the grid according to that.

Comment: `only 100 records should be retrieved` This is not the answer of OP.

Comment: i think in these plugins you define the number of records to display.

Comment: Question is how to retrieve data from SQL Server. For example, using Skip and Take.

Comment: @Win he is looking for grid as you can see first show 100 records and on next 2nd page....

Comment: These plugins can be customized according to the requirement.  If he want to show the 100 records then set the option of plugin......

Comment: My first priority is 'performance'.. how I can be able to fetch record from the database using some database paging technique..instead of fetching huge amount of records, I would like to fetch ..batch by batch to avoid performance issue..  Displaying the data comes next.. of course, a best design to implement such feature must be considered.. Basically I am looking for a best n efficient way..

Comment: It has both options to load data at once or page wise. you have to configure it and create query on server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple fast and way then think in using jQuery plugins like these

[jpaging](http://do-web.com/jpaging/overview)  OR   [datatables](http://datatables.net/).

you should search for design pattern for this.

kindly look at this [Easily build powerful client-side AJAX paging, using jQuery](http://encosia.com/easily-build-powerful-client-side-ajax-paging-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of both asp.net and C# makes me (probably because I am partial to it) think "WebMatrix". If, indeed you are using WebMatrix, check out its Grid Helper.  However, be warned that this method can generate some very serious overhead for your html page (by that I mean that if you query 1,000 rows and only use 100 per page, it will retrieve all 1,000, use 100, and waste the other 900). Also, using the WebGrid generates the results in a table, which may not be your preferred style.

Alternatively (still thinking "WebMatrix"), you could use this article here (this is my preferred method): http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/150/Web-Pages-Efficient-Paging-Without-The-WebGrid

Don't worry, that article is explained with EXCELLENT brevity and accuracy (and explained better than I could, so I leave it to Mike to vicariously answer that one).